# How to convert CSV to ORC format using Azure Datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, orc, snappy

I am coping comma separated partition data files into ADLS using azure datafactory.

The requirement is to copy the comma separated files to ORC format with SNAPPY compression.

Is it possible to achieve this with ADF? if yes, then could you please help me?

Comment: The ADF copy activity does support ORC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#orc-format However, it does not support SNAPPY when writing, only ZLIB. If that does not work for you, you could write a very simple Databricks job and call that from ADF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, data factory can **read** from ZLIB and SNAPPY, but can only **write** ZLIB, which is the default for the orc file format.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#orc-format

Hope this helped!!